# Make specific page in magento as not cacheable

Tags: magento2.3, cms, caching

I want to make a specific cms page to be set as a non-cacheable page.

Is there is a way to add XML code in layout update to achieve same

[image]

I'm calling block in page HTML with code as below

```
<p>{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Theme::html/test.phtml"}}</p>
```

Comment: Just add [cacheable="false" ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below code to achieve it using XML.

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="test_view" template="Magento_Theme::html/test.phtml"/>
```

To make the page non-cacheable you can use `cacheable` attribute.

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="test_view" template="Magento_Theme::html/test.phtml" cacheable="false" />
```

Hope this helps!